# Trigger Keyboard Click via Javascript

Tags: javascript

Jquery/Javascript event trigger does not seem to trigger the active element.

I have a play/pause button and am trying to toggle between them via Javascript. When using my physical keyboard and hit the Enter key, I see that it toggles between them. When trying to trigger it via code, it seems to not actually do anything.

A few things I have tried:

```
jQuery.event.trigger({type: 'keyup', which : 13});
```

`jQuery.event.trigger({type: 'keydown', which : 13});`

```
document.activeelement.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keypress',{'key':'enter'}));
```

I would think one of these would actually act like the enter key and press the play/pause.

Any ideas?

Comment: Actual keystrokes can not be triggered in JavaScript. Instead, just initiate the action(s) that would have been initiated if the keystroke had occurred.

Comment: One thing to add, it could be any button, not just play/pause. Was wondering if there was a way to do it on document.activeelement?

Answer (score 1):

For triggering a specific keypress, create a jQuery keypress `Event`, set which key to emulate, and trigger the created event on your DOM object, which could be your player.

```
var e = $.Event('keypress');
e.which = 13; // Enter key
$('#my-player').trigger(e);
```

As @ScottMarcus mentioned in the comment, a better idea would be to trigger the actions taken by your keypress event and not the event itself. For example, if you have the following event set:

```
$('#my-player').keypress(function(e) {
  if (e.which == 13) {
    togglePlayButton();
  }
});
```

You could instead call `togglePlayButton();` directly where you'd like to emulate the keypress. Do not sacrifice code clarity just for that though.

Comment: One thing to add, it could be any button, not just play/pause. Was wondering if there was a way to do it on document.activeelement?

Comment: @sql-noob are you looking for pressing enter and triggering the keypress event of the active element on the page?